# C++ template returning tuple with typename-values

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tuples, typename

In my journey to implement a template-based linked-list which works with key/value-pairs I want to implement a "`popHead()`"-method. However, I can't get it to compile.

```
/**
 * Removes the first element in the list and returns it.
 * @return first element, nullptr if list is empty
 */
std::tuple<K, V> popHead() {
    auto tmp = head;
    if (tmp) {
        if (tmp->next) {
            head = tmp->next;
        } else {
            head = nullptr;
        }
        return new std::tuple(tmp->key, tmp->value);
    }

    return nullptr;
};
```

This doesn't work because a type-specified is expected. Ok so it doesn't know what kind of type the values contained by the tuple should have.. however.. this doesn't work either:

```
return new std::tuple<K, V>(tmp->key, tmp->value);
```

How do I return a tuple with types `<K, V>`?

Comment: Nitpick: `if (tmp->next) ... ` can just be `head = tmp->next;`, you aren't dereferencing it

Comment: This question is confusing. Your prototype clearly returns an object, but you are trying to return `nullptr` and the result of `new` which are both pointers. Is `popHead` a member method? What does the class look like? What do you mean by template-based? Is this a template metaprogramming type? Pointers and template metaprogramming don't always mix well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
return {tmp->key, tmp->value};
```

?

Or, maybe, you want return a **pointer** to a `std::tuple<K, V>` ?

In this case

```
return new std::tuple<K, V>(tmp->key, tmp->value);
```

should work but you have to modify the return type

```
std::tuple<K, V> * popHead()
// --------------^ *pointer* to tuple
```

Comment: the interface of the class specifies popHead() to have this signature:  `std::tuple<K, V> popHead();`. This probably means my idea of returning nullptr if the list is empty won't work anyway. I'm mildly confused now.

Comment: @octavio instead of returning, you can `throw` or exhibit undefined behaviour

Comment: @octavio - if you need an object and not a pointer, you can't return `nullptr`; I think that the solution suggested by Caleth (instead of `return nullptr;`, throw an exception) is extremely reasonable.

Comment: @max66 yes, i'm throwing an exception instead now. thx guys, should've given the function-signature a better look. i've got it working now!

Comment: @octavio - and look also at the other suggestion from `Caleth`: instead of `if (tmp->next) { head = tmp->next; } else { head = nullptr; }`, you can simply write `head = tmp->next;`, avoiding an un-useful test.